# Error when running Rcpp in linux batch mode

Tags: r, linux, rcpp

I am trying to run a very simple model with rstan in batch mode and have some errors. I do not have any errors when I try to run the same code not in batch mode.

The community from [STAN Forums](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/error-when-running-rstan-in-linux-batch-mode/25699) helped me to understand that the issue is that Rcpp instead of STAN is not working properly on the server of my university. We reached this understanding from a test trying to run a very simple Rcpp code in batch mode and not in batch mode. The Rcpp code is:

```
### Libraries
library(Rcpp)

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
  #include <Rcpp.h>

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  int fibonacci(const int x) {
    if (x == 0) return(0);
    if (x == 1) return(1);
    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
  }',
                verbose = TRUE,
                rebuild = TRUE
)
```

The results are below.

Not in batch mode:

```
Generated R functions
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/tmp/RtmpDNL6of/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7/sourcecpp_178b21d435d91/sourceCpp_4.so')

fibonacci <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function(x) {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_1_fibonacci')

rm(`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /tmp/RtmpDNL6of/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7/sourcecpp_178b21d435d91

/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB --preclean -o 'sourceCpp_4.so' 'file178b25628f5ea.cpp'
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/tmp/RtmpDNL6of/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7" -I/hpc/apps/zlib/1.2.8/include -I/hpc/apps/pcre/8.38/include -I/hpc/apps/bzip2/1.0.6/include -I/hpc/apps/curl/7.54.1/include -I/hpc/apps/cairo/1.14.12/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c file178b25628f5ea.cpp -o file178b25628f5ea.o
g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -L/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/lib -L/hpc/apps/zlib/1.2.8/lib -L/hpc/apps/pcre/8.38/lib -L/hpc/apps/bzip2/1.0.6/lib -L/hpc/apps/curl/7.54.1/lib -L/hpc/apps/cairo/1.14.12/lib -o sourceCpp_4.so file178b25628f5ea.o -L/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

In batch mode:

```
Generated R functions 
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/localscratch/250948.1.ragatkolab.q/RtmpDlK5Sy/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7/sourcecpp_142bd68d660f1/sourceCpp_2.so')

fibonacci <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function(x) {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_1_fibonacci')

rm(`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /localscratch/250948.1.mylab.q/RtmpDlK5Sy/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7/sourcecpp_142bd68d660f1

/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_2.so' 'file142bd64ebe902.cpp' 
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/localscratch/250948.1.ragatkolab.q/RtmpDlK5Sy/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7" -I/hpc/apps/zlib/1.2.8/include -I/hpc/apps/pcre/8.38/include -I/hpc/apps/bzip2/1.0.6/include -I/hpc/apps/curl/7.54.1/include -I/hpc/apps/cairo/1.14.12/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c file142bd64ebe902.cpp -o file142bd64ebe902.o
In file included from /hpc/apps/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:524,
                 from /hpc/apps/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/cmath:41,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:66,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from file142bd64ebe902.cpp:2:
/hpc/apps/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:39:10: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
   39 | #include <features.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [file142bd64ebe902.o] Error 1
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = "\n  #include <Rcpp.h>\n\n  // [[Rcpp::export]]\n  int fibonacci(const int x) {\n    if (x == 0) return(0);\n    if (x == 1) return(1);\n    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);\n  }",  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install GNU development tools including a C++ compiler.

Execution halted
```

Then, they asked me to modify my makevars file - which I did using the R-package `usethis::edit_r_makevars()` - adding the lines:

```
CXXFLAGS += -I"/hpc/apps/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/parallel/"
CXX14FLAGS += -I"/hpc/apps/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/parallel/"
```

Once I did this modification (I hope I did it correctly), my error message change to:

```
Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>
#ifdef RCPP_USE_GLOBAL_ROSTREAM
Rcpp::Rostream<true>&  Rcpp::Rcout = Rcpp::Rcpp_cout_get();
Rcpp::Rostream<false>& Rcpp::Rcerr = Rcpp::Rcpp_cerr_get();
#endif

// fibonacci
int fibonacci(const int x);
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_1_fibonacci(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const int >::type x(xSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(fibonacci(x));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}

Generated R functions 
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/localscratch/251578.1.mylablab.q/RtmpCHyEAd/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7/sourcecpp_1e50364a03315/sourceCpp_2.so')

fibonacci <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function(x) {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_1_fibonacci')

rm(`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /localscratch/251578.1.mylablab.q/RtmpCHyEAd/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7/sourcecpp_1e50364a03315

/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_2.so' 'file1e50325e7686.cpp' 
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/hpc/apps/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/localscratch/251578.1.mylablab.q/RtmpCHyEAd/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.7" -I/hpc/apps/zlib/1.2.8/include -I/hpc/apps/pcre/8.38/include -I/hpc/apps/bzip2/1.0.6/include -I/hpc/apps/curl/7.54.1/include -I/hpc/apps/cairo/1.14.12/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -I"/hpc/apps/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/parallel/" -c file1e50325e7686.cpp -o file1e50325e7686.o
In file included from /hpc/apps/gcc/11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:571,
                 from /hpc/apps/gcc/11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/cmath:41,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:66,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from file1e50325e7686.cpp:2:
/hpc/apps/gcc/11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   44 | #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
      |                   ^
/hpc/apps/gcc/11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:52:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   52 | #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2, 27)
      |                   ^
In file included from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:66,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from /hpc/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from file1e50325e7686.cpp:2:
/hpc/apps/gcc/11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/cmath:45:15: fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory
   45 | #include_next <math.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [file1e50325e7686.o] Error 1
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = "\n  #include <Rcpp.h>\n\n  // [[Rcpp::export]]\n  int fibonacci(const int x) {\n    if (x == 0) return(0);\n    if (x == 1) return(1);\n    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);\n  }",  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install GNU development tools including a C++ compiler.

Execution halted
```

My knowledge in Linux is limited and I am afraid that my question is out of scope for STAN Forums. Any thoughts how to proceed?

Comment: You showed us pages worth of error messages but you did not show us _how_ you generate error. I am not an active user of (r)stan, but whether you R interactively or in batch does _not_ matter.  R knows where the compiler uses is, and finds,  But somehow _in just your setup_ something is different when you use batch mode.  We cannot guess why.  You have to find that, and we can try to help you but we need more detail.   _Maybe_ all it takes is for you to create a `~/.R/Makevars` file,  How do that is both in the R docs, and in many questions on this site.

Comment: Thanks. I added the Rcpp code that generated my errors. I created a `Makevars` file, edited CXXFLAGS and CXX14FLAGS paths, but I still got an error, which is different from the previous error though.

Answer (score 2):

I fear your problem is still local. On the computing you use, *someone* may have set up R in way that makes it differ between interactive R use, and what you call batch use.

But that is non-standard, and at your end. In general, it just works.  Using a minimally modified version of your program (which I still find confusing: it loads `doParallel`, registers cores but ... triggers to parallel code -- anyway) it works just fine:

##### Using Rscript

```
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/70470842(master)$ Rscript answer.R  
Loading required package: foreach        
Loading required package: iterators      
Loading required package: parallel       
Fib(10) is  55                           
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/70470842(master)$
```

##### Using R in batch mode

```
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/70470842(master)$ R -s -f answer.R 
Loading required package: foreach     
Loading required package: iterators   
Loading required package: parallel    
Fib(10) is  55                        
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/70470842(master)$
```

##### Using our littler frontend

```
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/70470842(master)$ r answer.R     
Loading required package: foreach               
Loading required package: iterators             
Loading required package: utils                 
Loading required package: parallel              
Fib(10) is  55                                  
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/70470842(master)$
```

##### Modified source code

```
library(doParallel)             # Library        

ncores <- 5                     # Simulation parameters
n_sim <- 5                  
registerDoParallel(ncores)  

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='  
  #include <Rcpp.h>     
  // [[Rcpp::export]]            
  int fibonacci(const int x) {   
    if (x == 0) return(0);       
    if (x == 1) return(1);       
    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2); 
  }'          
  )           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
cat("Fib(10) is ", fibonacci(10), "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks. The parallelization was from my old and more complex code running STAN. I cleaned it up. The error is still the same. I also think that is local! In my past experience, Rcpp would run without issues in the cluster. Is there any additional step that I can do to understand how R and Rcpp were set up differently in this cluster?

Comment: _Now_ we're getting closer. It is, after all, all about _minimally_ reproducible example. So no `(r)stan`, no `doParallel` use, just you and your compiler settings with R.  That does not even involve `Rcpp` (though it helps tickle the compile command).  I would start by looking at what the R you run has in its $RHOME/etc/Makeconf and then compare between the _working_ and _not-working / "batch"_ use what the values of `CC`, `CXX`, ... are.  In one case R is told what to use now (possibly different from what it was compiled with), it the other it isn't.  You have to learn what is missing.

Comment: I checked the path for `Makeconf` file in batch and interactive mode. Both use the same file.

Comment: That was not really my suggestion, we know the file exists.  But one of the two modes gets extra overrides to find your non-standard compiler path. You have to find out how/where/why.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I interacted with IT team from my institution after feedback received here and STAN Forums, and they finally found a solution. In their words:

"Compute nodes aren't normally used for development. So certain development packages are not installed by default.  We installed "glibc-devel" and "glibc-headers" on the compute nodes.

So, it seems that when run interactively the job was running on the submit node (which had these libraries installed) and when run from the scheduler it was run on the compute nodes (which did not have the library installed).  The reason for the discrepancy being that the libraries in question have traditionally been only used during development and compilation.  This use posed a unique use case."